# Putting an integer into a character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

As I have been looking on this topic for a lot of time on this site, I couldn't find a helpful solution to my problem.
So here's my problem :

If I have any number, say **num = 256**, I want to save this number in a character array, say **a[10]**, like :

```
a[0] = 2
a[1] = 5
a[2] = 6
Storing in their respective indices
```

also the **num** variable is not static and it's value is dynamically entered by the user on runtime. But the size of the character array will be static.

Comment: You can get the rightmost digit of a number by `num%10`. With `num/10` you can shift the number to the right. So you can write a loop that can do it.

Comment: what code did you write, what problem did you face? Do you know how to get individual digits from a number?

Comment: why the size of the character array is static? What should happen if the user enters `123456789` but you only have space for 3 digits?

Comment: What is it you're asking? It looks like you know how to assign an index into a character array, do you need help getting this input from the user?

Comment: So, to be clear, you don't want the character array to contain the digits of the number but the *values* of the digits of the number. That is, for the number two-hundred and fifty six, you want the array to contain the number of hands I have, the number of fingers on each hand, and the number of legs a spider has, is that correct? Not the digits, "2", "5", "6". Please confirm this.

Comment: Do you want `a[0] = 2;` (an integer) or `a[0] = '2';` (a character) in your array? What about the number of digits in your array, presumably you need to store that somewhere? Half the battle with these kind of questions is understanding and expressing clearly what you actually want.

Comment: What should be stored for a negative number like `-123`?

Comment: @john an integer

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo There's no scope for a negative number

Comment: @VaibhavSharma Do you mean that negative numbers are forbidden (I don't quite understand _scope_ in this context)?

Comment: @David Schwartz Nah man, I want to store the actual value!

Comment: @Unlikus Will surely try to implement that

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I just meant that negative numbers will not be entered

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an integral value to its decimal representation with [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
std::string const dec = std::to_string(num);
```

If you have a character array, say `char a[4]`, you can copy the data there element-wise:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; std::begin(a) + i < std::end(a) && i < dec.size(); ++i) {
  a[i] = dec[i] - '0';
}
```

---

Edit: See [Konrad Rudolph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63574802/430766) for a simpler (and presumably faster) way of doing this.

Comment: `a[0] = 2` not `'2'`, tripped me up too :)

Answer (score 2):

C++17 has [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) for this purpose:

```
char a[10];

if (auto const result = std::to_chars(a, a + sizeof a - 1, 256); result.ec != std::errc()) {
    // An error occurred.
} else {
    *result.ptr = '\0';
}
```

Comment: it should be just `a + sizeof a`, the second argument is an exclusive bound.

Comment: @J.Schultke No, because `std::to_chars` does not add the zero-termination. We need to leave space for that and add it manually. Otherwise, `std::to_chars` would “succeed” when being passed a `char[3]`, even though that’s not big enough to store `{'2', '5', '6', '\0'}`.

Comment: `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)` for arrays is guaranteed to return a raw pointer, so the call could be rewritten as `std::to_chars(std::begin(a),std::prev(std::end(a)), num)`.

Comment: PS: That would have the advantage that an unintentional pointer decay of `a` would not result in a silent error (with potentially disastrous consequences) but a compilation error. Also it is harder to mess up the calculation of `std::to_chars`'s `last` argument.

Answer (score 1):

a way is decomposing the number in hundred, tens and units... modulo can help and log10 will be useful too:

this is going to be a nice work around if you arent allowed to convert to string

here an example:

```
int value = 256;
int myArray[3];
auto m = static_cast<int>(ceil(log10(value)));
for(int i =0; i < m; ++i)
{
    myArray[m-1-i] = static_cast<int>(value/pow(10,i))%10;
}
```